# binding словаря через caliburn.micro к combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

Задал словарь через свойство

```
private Dictionary<int, string> _muscleGroupExercise;

public Dictionary<int, string> MuscleGroupExercise
{
     get { return _muscleGroupExercise; }
     set
     {
         _muscleGroupExercise = managerController.GetMuscleGroupExercise();
         OnPropertyChanged("MuscleGroupExercise");
     }
}
```

XML разметка

```
 <ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,0,5" Width="200"/>
```

Вопрос. Как грамотно сделать binding MuscleGroupExercise к ComboBox использую фрейм caliburn.micro, необходим значение MuscleGroupExercise + учесть что так же будет реализована обработка выбранного элемента, гуглил, но видимо криво, ответа на вопрос найти не смог. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding MuscleGroupExercise}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedMuscleGroupExerciseId}"`

Comment: @aepot Да получилось, проблема правда в другом была. нужно было инициализации переписать private Dictionary<int, string> _muscleGroupExercise => managerController.GetMuscleGroupExercise();

        public Dictionary<int, string> MuscleGroupExercise
        {
            get { return _muscleGroupExercise; }
        } и сделать биндинг как вы указали.

Comment: Намудрили, теперь у вас _muscleGroupExercise не поле, а свойство. Что вам мешает написать так? `public Dictionary<int, string> MuscleGroupExercise => managerController.GetMuscleGroupExercise();` и выкинуть приватное свойство совсем?

Comment: @aepot, действительно, вы правы. получается коротко и лаконично, благодарю Вас за помощь!

Comment: @aepot, селект также отлично работает. public int _selectedMuscleGroupExerciseId;

public int SelectedMuscleGroupExerciseId {
            get { return _selectedMuscleGroupExerciseId; }
            set
            {
                _selectedMuscleGroupExerciseId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedMuscleGroupExerciseId");
            }
        }

Comment: Только учтите один момент, вы не кешируете `MuscleGroupExercise` нигде, и при каждом обращении к этому словарю, будет вызываться  метод `GetMuscleGroupExercise()` чтобы исправить это, можете попробовать вернуть приватное поле и написать вот так `public Dictionary<int, string> MuscleGroupExercise => _muscleGroupExercise ??= managerController.GetMuscleGroupExercise();`, тогда метод вызовется только один раз при первом обращении к свойству, потом же значение будет просто сохранено в приватном поле и будет браться оттуда.

Comment: @aepot, обращу на это внимание, спасибо.